# Links in navbar doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one page site created with Bootstrap. On this page header links are like this:

```
<header id="section_header" class="navbar-fixed-top main-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
             <div class="navbar-header ">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="" alt="biZkvitki.bg">
                    </a>
             </div><!--Navbar header End-->
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navigation" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                        <li class="active"> <a href="#slider_part">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio"  >Portfolio</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#about" >About</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#team" >Team</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#blog" >Blog</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#contact" >Contacts</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </header>
```

On that page everything work fine. What I try is to recreate this header in every internal page but when I try to make links like this they doesn't work. Nothing happen when I click on them. The idea is when user is on some internal page and click `About` for example to load index page section about.. What I'm missing here?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
    <li class="active"> <a href="../index.php#slider_part">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../index.php#portfolio"  >Portfolio</a> </li>
    <li><a href="../index.php#about" >About</a> </li>
    <li><a href="../index.php#team" >Team</a> </li>
    <li><a href="../index.php#blog" >Blog</a> </li>
    <li><a href="../index.php#contact" >Contacts</a> </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE: I believe this is the `.js` which is for the navbar

```
jQuery(function($) {
"use strict";

 $('.navigation').singlePageNav({
    currentClass: 'active',
    changeHash: true,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    offset: 0,
    filter: ':not(.external)',
    easing: 'swing',

});

$.noConflict();
 $('.nav a').on('click', function(){ 
    if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
        $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
    }
});




// accordian
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.panel-group').children().each(function(){
  $(this).find('>.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
 });

$(this).closest('.panel-heading').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Are all the pages in the same folder?

Comment: Yes except the `header.php` file

Comment: About the anchors, are they handler by a js script like scroll to animate?

Comment: Is this site live or are you running it locally from your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yeah, i knew that js script make the trouble!
A solution should be to call you script only on your index.php because on another page the script prevent normal links behavior.
If you dont want to remove your script on another page, you need to detect your index page like:

```
<body id="home-page">
```

And on your script:

```
 $('#home-page .navigation')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a local computer you need to add the name of your site folder as well that holds all of your site files.  For example `../"name of site"/index.php#portfolio`  If your site is live, add the entire site address before index for example `http://"name of site"/index.php#portfolio`

Comment: I've tried but still nothing. I click on the link and nothing happen like I didn't clicked at all. Also I've updated my question with the `js` of the bar..

Answer (score 1):

You're using anchor links so you'll just move up and down the same page.

Make sure that you have your id's setup properly.

```
<div id="portfolio">Portfolio</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The links on the page that works are local and that's why they work fine:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
  ...
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#about"    >About</a>     </li>
```

The links on the other pages are not local (not local bookmarks) according to single page navigation since they start with a relative path:

```
<li><a href="../index.php#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
<li><a href="../index.php#about"    >About</a>     </li>
```

Notice that there is a filter when you call "singlePageNav":

```
 $('.navigation').singlePageNav({
    currentClass: 'active',
    changeHash  : true,
    scrollSpeed : 750,
    offset      : 0,
    filter      : ':not(.external)',
    easing      : 'swing',

});
```

If you add that filter class to your anchors, they should work fine:

```
<li><a class="external" href="../index.php#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
<li><a class="external" href="../index.php#about"    >About</a>     </li>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This is something i often come across when working with bootstrap. You are probably using the ScrollTo.js because you most likely just copy/pasted the whole page onto a new one. So (if you don't really need it) just delete the   from your head section, or at the bottom before the closing body tag.